# delphi lose value when freeing object

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Sorry if there's the same question with mine.

In Delphi i make function like this:

```
function TModuleDatabase.LoadCountryList():TDictionary<integer, String>;
var
  UQ: TUniQuery;
  UC: TUniConnection;
  CountryList: TDictionary<integer, String>;
begin
  CountryList := TDictionary<integer, String>.Create;
  UC := UniConnection2;
  UQ := TUniQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    UQ.Connection := UC;
    try
      UQ.SQL.Clear;
      UQ.SQL.Add('SELECT ID,NAME FROM COUNTRY ORDER BY NAME ASC');
      UQ.Open;
      while not UQ.Eof do
      begin
        CountryList.Add(UQ.Fields.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger,UQ.Fields.FieldByName('NAME').AsString);
        UQ.Next;
      end;
      Result := CountryList;
    except
      on E:Exception do
        ModuleMsgDialog.WarningMsg(E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    UQ.Close;
    UQ.Free;
    CountryList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I separate the function to other DataModule to make me not repeat this function every time in each form. But when i call this funtion from a form:

```
procedure TCompanyDetailsForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  sItem: String;
  CountryList: TDictionary<integer, String>;
begin
  PageControl1.ActivePage := AddressTab;

  CountryList := ModuleDatabase.LoadCountryList();
  for i in CountryList.Keys do
  begin
    LocationCbbx.Items.AddObject(CountryList.Items[i],TObject(i));
  end;
end;
```

The Problem is at **CountryList.Free;**. All item in dictionary already freed before use.
If i don't do free, there will make memory leaks.

How the best ways to transfer data before doing free. Or how to free value at other form or unit after call.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should use something like `procedure TModuleDatabase.LoadCountryList( countries : TDictionary<integer, String> );`. This way, the calling code will (have to) provide an instance of the dictionary and the caller will also be responsible for freeing it when it's time to do so.

Comment: You could *probably* make the TDictionary a field of your TModuleDatabase and all your forms could share the same instance instead of each having their own copies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two main options.

**Option 1 – Caller provides an instantiated object**

Here you let the caller take responsibility for lifetime. The caller passes in an instantiated object, the callee populates it.

```
procedure PopulateCountryDict(Countries: TDictionary<Integer, string>);
begin
  // populate Countries here
end;
```

**Option 2 – Caller returns a newly instantiated object, which is also populated**

This is viable, but the caller has to assume responsibility for the lifetime once the callee returns. It looks like this:

```
function CreateAndPopulateCountryDict: TDictionary<Integer, string>;
begin
  Result := TDictionary<Integer, string>.Create;
  try
    // populate Result here
  except
    Result.Free; // until this function returns, we are responsible for lifetime
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

The calling code looks like this:

```
var
  Countries: TDictionary<Integer, string>
....
Countries := CreateAndPopulateCountryDict;
try
  // do stuff with Countries
finally
  Countries.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Yes.. yes.. I don't think of that. I think i will going with option 1, because it safer and enough to accomplish what i need. Option 2 makes me have to be more careful with try clause.

Thank you David for your fast respond.

Answer (score 2):

As an extension to David's answer there is another option using a callback

```
procedure LoadCountryList( ACallback : TProc<TDictionary<integer,string>> );
var
  LCountryList : TDictionary<integer,string>;
begin
  // create the instance
  LCountryList := TDictionary<integer,string>.Create;
  try
    // fill the dictionary

    // execute the callback
    ACallback( LCountryList );
  finally
    // free the instance
    LCountryList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

and then use this in your code

```
procedure TCompanyDetailsForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PageControl1.ActivePage := AddressTab;

  LoadCountryList( 
    procedure ( CountryList : TDictionary<integer,string> ) 
    var
      i: Integer;
    begin
      for i in CountryList.Keys do
      begin
        LocationCbbx.Items.AddObject(CountryList.Items[i],TObject(i));
      end;
    end );
end;
```

Comment: More advanced solution for me here. Many ways to go to Rome. I think this answer will be overkill for my question.  :D  But this also very useful. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should create dictinary in FormCreate method, and destroy or clear where do you need. Not in LoadCountryList function.

Comment: Yep i agree with you. And also Mr. David reply answered my question clearly with sample.

Thank you for your help.